# How to make a continuously upcounting txt file?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a code block that creates a series of .txt file names.  It will open a new file and prompt the user to enter text for the file, continuing until the user doesn't want any more files.

How do I get it to create a series of file names such as **file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt**, etc. ?

Comment: Keep a numeric variable, convert it to a string when choosing a filename, increase it by 1 each time you're finished with a file.

Comment: Can you show some code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you do know in advance how many files are required you can pass a start value to the function [*range()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range)

```
fnum = 10
fname = 'file'
ext = '.txt'

for i in range(1, fnum + 1):
    with open("{fname}{fnum}{ext}".format(fname=fname, fnum=i, ext=ext), 'w') as f:
    # OR for Python 3.6+
    # with open(f'{fname}{i}{ext}', 'w') as f:
        print(input('User Input: '), file=f)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
filenum = 1
while # getting input from user
    outfile = open ("userfile" + str(filenum), 'w')
    filenum += 1
    # rest of your loop
```